# Can you please figure out the error with my code?

Tags: android, database, android-layout, cursor, indexoutofboundsexception

Basically, In this app i am trying to find out the doctor's list of a particular nursing home.In my 2nd activity there are two Button one is for User another is for Admin. User can visualize the Doctor's list with Specialization, whatever Admin will add.

```
        package com.example.lenovo.finalproject;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.database.SQLException;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.Spinner;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import java.util.ArrayList;


        public class MainActivity5 extends Activity {

            private final String DB_NAME = "My_DB2";
            private final String TB_NAME = "TB2";

            SQLiteDatabase db;

            Spinner sp;
            ListView l;
            String str[] = {"Orthopaedics", "Cardiologist"};
            String special;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity5);


                // open the database
                db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

                sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
                l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);


                final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, str);
                sp.setAdapter(adapter);
                sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                        special = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().trim();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), special, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });

                // open the database
                // db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);



                initListViewData();

            }

            private void initListViewData() {
                String selectQuery = " SELECT * FROM " + TB_NAME + " where speciality " + " = " + special;// problem arising these line//
                String did;
                String name;
                String speciality;
                String time;
                String fees;
                Cursor c = null;

                try {
                    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
                    c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                    if (c != null) {
                        // if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        c.moveToFirst();

                        do {
                            did = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
                            name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
                            speciality = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("speciality"));
                            time = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time"));
                            fees = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fees"));
                            String s = did + "\n " + name + "\n " + speciality + " \n" + time + "\n " + fees;
                            listItems.add(s);

                        } while (c.moveToNext());
                        // }
                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
                        // l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                        l.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " No records found..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    se.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (null != c) {
                        c.close();
                    }
                }

            }

            void show() {

            }
```

In `MainActivity4.java` data is adding .which is connected through an Intent to this activity.

The Problem is occur when i am using Spinner in this activity. The line using String query is making the problem. If i am using this line with out spinner it will works.Kindly go trough the code once again if you will find out any error or any line which will be needed to include.

I am using Android Studion , API 19 (Jellybean).

Whenever I am trying to click the User button it shows that Unfortunately your app has stopped working. Following error shows in logcat

```
07-14 23:42:56.945    1853-1853/com.example.lenovo.finalproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lenovo.finalproject/com.example.lenovo.finalproject.MainActivity5}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
            at com.example.lenovo.finalproject.MainActivity5.initListViewData(MainActivity5.java:90)
            at com.example.lenovo.finalproject.MainActivity5.onCreate(MainActivity5.java:69)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)

Your *cursor* doesn't contain any data

You need to validate `Cursor`. If your cursor count is more then `0` then and then only you need to fetch data from cursor.

So Change like this

```
 if (c != null & c.getCount > 0) {
                        // if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        c.moveToFirst();

                        do {
                            did = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
                            name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
                            speciality = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("speciality"));
                            time = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time"));
                            fees = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fees"));
                            String s = did + "\n " + name + "\n " + speciality + " \n" + time + "\n " + fees;
                            listItems.add(s);

                        }
```

Comment: Thanks it working. But Even adding data it shows no record found

Comment: If possible kindly send me your mail  id.. i will send you my file

Comment: It's ok. Actually it's look like there is some data but due to some reason it doesn't shows.

Comment: @SubhenduRoy it work if put some effort on it. and try to debug it..Happy Coding..

Comment: Whenever i am trying to run my app, it doesn't stopped working but is shows this message "Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397854/attempting-to-finish-an-input-event-but-the-input-event-receiver-has-already-bee/38398152#38398152.. kindly check this link ...

Answer (score 0):

Your error `Index 0 requested, with a size of 0` says everything. `Cursor` is not having data and you are trying to fetch record from 0th position.

Just uncomment `// if  (c.moveToFirst()) {` this line from your code and it will work.

Or else you can go with [Ironman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38387727/3134215) also, both will work.